# Regex to include empty matches with non-empty ones

Tags: regex

I need to regex every match of a string (including empty string!) separated by slash but the regex returns also empty string after each occurrence.

Examples (always 4 matches):

```
root/level1/level2/level3
/level1//level3
root/level1/level2/
```

Pattern:

- `[^\/]*` - return 8 matches (empty string after and before ) instead of 4

I also tried to use IF-THEN-ELSE clause but it did not help :-(

[My regex playground](https://regex101.com/r/AoNKsy/1)

I've searched dozens of articles but did not find any solution.

Comment: Use `[^\/]+` to match *1 or more* characters other than `/`.

Comment: I does not solve my problem. This would work for only matches non empty strings but as I've written - I need both.

Comment: You mean you need [`[^\/]+|(?<=\/)(?=\/)`](https://regex101.com/r/jBoDQ8/1)?

Comment: Better but not perfect. Take a look at the link below. I need 5 matches but have only 3:

https://regex101.com/r/pxRXEc/1

Comment: `[^\/]+|(?<=\/|^)(?=\/|$)`, https://regex101.com/r/pxRXEc/2

Comment: That's it! :) Thank you very much. How can I select your comments as the right answer? Sorry, this was my first question on stackoverflow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
[^\/]+|(?<=\/|^)(?=\/|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pxRXEc/2) and the regex graph:

[image]

**Details**

- `[^\/]+` - 1+ chars other than `/`
- `|` - or
- `(?<=\/|^)(?=\/|$)` - a location that is immediately preceded with `/` or start of string and immediately followed with `/` or end of string.